# Nest not loading dependencies

Tags: nestjs

nest throws this Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, UserRepository). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

**users module:**

```
@Module({
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]), NewsModule],
providers: [UsersService],
controllers: [UsersController],
exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

**News Module**

```
@Module({
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([New]), HttpModule],
controllers: [NewsController],
providers: [NewsService],
exports: [NewsService],
})
export class NewsModule {}
```

**Users Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
constructor(
private readonly newsService: NewsService,
@InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, UserRepository). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

Nest can't figure out the class name `NewsService`, as the error says `dependency` instead of the class. This happens when there is a circular reference between file imports, but not between the classes themselves. Check the imports of `users.service.ts`, `users.module.ts`, `news.service.ts`, and `news.module.ts` and make sure you have no circlar import paths.